# Base64ImageField returns full url path only when parameter context={"request": request} added to it - Is there any other way

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I currently have a Base64ImageField which works totally fine. The only problem I am having is sometimes it returns back an incomplete path. It skips the domain name but the rest of the path is fine.The reason its skipping the domain name is because I do not pass in the parameter `context={"request": request}` during serialization.The reason for that is because sometimes I do not have access to the request object.In other words this works fine

```
jsonObject = Serializer(model_instance,context={"request": request}).data
```

and this one skips the domain name from the image field

```
jsonObject = Serializer(model_instance).data
```

My question is how can I make it return the full url path using the second example when I do not have to the request object ? Or is there any way for me to obtain the request object. When its not available ?

I have this serializer in my code

```
class Serializer_Employer_TX(ModelSerializer):
    user = Serializer_User()
    employer_image = Base64ImageField(max_length=None, use_url=True, required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = modelEmployer
        fields = [
            'user',
            'employer_zip',
            'employer_image',
        ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`sites` framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/), and override [`to_representation` method](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#to_representationself-obj) of `Serializer_Employer_TX`

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site


class Serializer_Employer_TX(ModelSerializer):

    user = Serializer_User()
    employer_image = Base64ImageField(max_length=None, use_url=True, required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = modelEmployer
        fields = [
            'user',
            'employer_zip',
            'employer_image',
        ]

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        """Convert `username` to lowercase."""
        ret = super().to_representation(instance)
        if  not 'request' in self.context:
            # You can tweaks the url in here directly
            current_site = Site.objects.get_current().domain
            ret['employer_image'] = current_site + ret['employer_image']

        return ret
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: This sounds promising could you tell me what to_representation does ? and when its called ?

Comment: Let me try that and get back to you

Comment: @Rajeshwar `to_representation()` - provided by `BaseSerializer` and `ModelSerializer`. Override this to support serialization, for **read operations**. more implementation details [here](http://www.cdrf.co/3.7/rest_framework.serializers/ModelSerializer.html#to_representation).